# Remove trailing commas in as .csv file is working on windows but not on Linux

Tags: python-2.7

```
Popen(['sed','-e','s/\(.*\),/\1/','C:\\Python27\\file_m.csv','>>','C:\\Python27\\file_m12454.csv'],shell=True)
```

It is changing nothing in my newly generated `CSV` but same works when run command on command prompt

Comment: can you add more explanation to your question and add some code too.

Comment: from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess as sp
import os

zk=Popen(['sed',r"'s/\(.*\),/\1/'",'C:\\Python27\\file_m.csv','>>','C:\\Python27\\file_m1245774.csv'],shell=True)   ...........................This code works for me on my windows machine (for removing trailing coma at last of each line in CSV file)   But same dont work on VM  for (linux) whats  wrong in this

Comment: did you change your absolute file path in the command while doing it? Execute it a python command line and share the output pls. I tried similar program in my Linux machine  *Popen("sed -e s/,*$//g afile.csv", shell=True)* and it worked fine as per your requirement. feel free to try this too.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me just        Popen("sed -e 's/,*$//g' afile.csv >> bfile.csv", shell=True)

Comment: Glad to help. I have updated it in the answer. If that answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
subprocess.Popen("sed -e 's/,*$//g' afile.csv", shell=True)
```

I tried a similar program on my Linux and Windows machine. It worked fine. Make sure to give the correct file path while trying it.